# How to solve: Installation request for orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle[dev-master]

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.8

I am installing a Symfony project when running composer install gives me the following error:

I have looked for there and usually recommend updating the symfony version but I cannot update it. In addition, the project is working on other equipment with the same composer.json

```sh
rick@mint:~/repos/myvitale$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.52
...
...
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.2
    - don't install symfony/var-dumper v3.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/var-dumper v3.0.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
...
...
...
    - orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle dev-master requires symfony/symfony >=2.0.12 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10,...  ....].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.1
    - Installation request for symfony/var-dumper ^3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v3.0.0, v3.0.1,
```

and this is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/",
            "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/SymfonyStandard/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "twig/twig": "<2.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.5.12",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.5",
        "twig/extensions": "1.4.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "1.5.2",
        "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.2.2",
        "orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/translation-bundle": "@stable",
        "jms/i18n-routing-bundle": "@stable",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.8.0",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "@stable",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "~2.3|3.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "^1.5",
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^3.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^3.20",
        "iio/libmergepdf": "~3.0",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "gree/jose": "^2.2",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.6",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
        "javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle": "^1.16",
        "willdurand/js-translation-bundle": "^2.6",
        "limenius/react-bundle": "^0.14.0",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "lynx39/lara-pdf-merger": "dev-master",
        "mikehaertl/php-pdftk": "^0.4.0",
        "gos/web-socket-bundle": "^1.8",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "0.12.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "symfony/property-access": "2.8.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "2.8.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7",
        "escapestudios/symfony2-coding-standard": "3.x-dev"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

This is happens in a usb live persistente ¿Is this important?

Answer (score 0):

The bundle you are trying to install seems to be ok, when looking [here](https://packagist.org/packages/orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle) you can see all the requirements for the bundle are achieved.

It may be a problem with the PHP version that is trying to use. Check which version is being used and make sure that is the right one (which I guess should be 5.6.40 because you're using Symfony 2.8). Then add `"php": ">=5.3.9,<6"` in the require section of your composer.json to limit the versions available to install.

Also add the platform which should be used (PHP version) in the config section of your composer.json ([documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform)).

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6.40"
    }
},
```

Also you probably need to use the `composer update` command for this to take effect and being applied to the composer.lock file.

Comment: Thanks @alexcm.
In the old pc the project works perfectly and the php -v is :

ricardo@ricardo-vitale:~/repos/myvitale$ php -v
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2020 15:55:52) ( NTS )
...

in the new one (the pc where the project doesn't work)

rick@mint:~$ php -v
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2020 15:55:52) ( NTS )
...


As you can see is the same version.  
Any clue?

Comment: Can you add the whole composer.json, just in case there is other dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The `symfony/symfony` package already includes the VarDumper component (which you try to install with the `symfony/var-dumper` package). This is something Composer wrongly allowed in older versions and was fixed in Composer 1.7.3.

Do you really need the VarDumper component in version 3.0.x? If that's the case, you need to remove `symfony/symfony` first and require all the needed components explicitly.